# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found - Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, drivers, network-interface

I have recently installed Linux

```
ach@ach-ZenBook-UX434IQ-UM433IQ:~$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

ach@ach-ZenBook-UX434IQ-UM433IQ:~$ uname -a
Linux ach-ZenBook-UX434IQ-UM433IQ 5.15.0-40-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 15 12:54:21 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But I was unable to connect to Wifi. When I open the network interface from the settings I get `No Wi-Fi Adapter Found`.

this is what I get when I list the hardware (network)

```
ach@ach-ZenBook-UX434IQ-UM433IQ:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc800000-fc803fff
```

This is the model of my PC just in case

```
ach@ach-ZenBook-UX434IQ-UM433IQ:~$ sudo dmidecode | grep -A8 '^System Information'
System Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: ZenBook UX434IQ_UM433IQ
    Version: 1.0       
    Serial Number: L7N0CV01182627C
    UUID: b56c3ea7-287e-bd4a-bd26-ba224a1c48eb
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number:  
    Family: ZenBook
```

EDIT*

Additional information about PCI buses

```
ach@ach-ZenBook-UX434IQ-UM433IQ:~$ lspci | grep AX200
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
```

and message bugger of the kernel

```
ach@ach-ZenBook-UX434IQ-UM433IQ:~$ sudo dmesg | grep firmware
[    0.132179] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    3.709761] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.713135] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi
[    4.071111] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x0101001F
[    4.072016] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.16 DEC: 5 VEP: 0 Revision: 3
[    4.072028] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    5.183258] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
```

I downloaded the driver from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html then copied the file to `/lib/firmware` as mentioned in the `README`.

```
ach@ach-ZenBook-UX434IQ-UM433IQ:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Operation not permitted

ach@ach-ZenBook-UX434IQ-UM433IQ:~$ sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-40-generic
```

After reboot I'm still getting nothing in dmesg

```
ach@ach-ZenBook-UX434IQ-UM433IQ:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: See `https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos`

Comment: You may want to use the latest released kernel which is 5.18.

Comment: Do you see the card in the `lspci` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Linux Wireless Wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi), Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 support was added to the standard Linux kernel in kernel version 5.1.

Since you have kernel version 5.15, you should already have the support in place.

However, most Intel WiFi chips need *firmware*, which is not stored persistently in the chip itself and must be loaded to the chip in every boot. The kernel will do this automatically if the firmware file is available to it. If you are missing a firmware file, there should be a message about it in `dmesg` output after boot: run `sudo dmesg | grep firmware` to see it.

The firmware files for all but the very newest Intel WiFi chips is included in the package `linux-firmware` on Ubuntu: run e.g. `sudo apt install linux-firmware` to ensure you have it installed.

If you have a WiFi chip version that needs newer firmware than is packaged by your distribution, you could download it yourself from the [linux-firmware git repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/). The repository's directory structure is similar to the `[/usr]/lib/firmware/` directory tree on your system: just find the missing firmware file based on the pathname listed in the error message in `dmesg`, download it using the link named "plain", and copy it to the appropriate location on your system.

If you have to install firmware manually, it's a good idea to rebuild your initramfs afterwards, so the new firmware will be available in the earliest phases of the boot process: on Debian and related distributions like Ubuntu, `sudo update-initramfs -u` should do it.

Comment: I installed the driver by copying the `ucode` file into `lib/firmware/` directory. in my case it's `iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode`. I'm still unable to see the module, I will update the post with the steps and results

Comment: The problem was, my BIOS do not save changes if I change from normal / advanced view. Therefore my secure boot state did not save, and was still enabled. disabling it solved the problem. Thanks for the detailed explanation on how to deal with such problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instal proprietars driver or build from sources. See it is on a github, for example. I was do it on a debian. He have a proprietars driverin your repo (search prefix *firmware*)